# Semaphore - How to Know when all functions are out of the queue?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I'm using a sempahore and I have the below code working correctly.  However, I'd like to improve it.  How do I write to the console once all Step1 functions have ran?

This is just a quick easy example of what I'm trying to accomplish in my actual application.

```
static SemaphoreSlim _sem = new SemaphoreSlim(5);

public void start()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        new Thread(Step1).Start(x);
    }
}

public void Step1(object o)
{
    try
    {
        _sem.Wait();

        int x = (int)o;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Step 1: {0}", x));
        new Thread(Step2).Start(x);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
    finally
    {
        _sem.Release();
    }
}

public void Step2(object o)
{
    try
    {
        _sem.Wait();

        int x = (int)o;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Step 2: {0}", x));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
    finally
    {
        _sem.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope this is only an attempt at understanding threading and not anything you ever want to use in code anywhere - if it is, just use `Task`s.

Comment: Why do you say that?  If you want to limit the number of threads running at any one time, you would want to use a semaphore to "queue" them right?

Comment: You really want to use the highest abstraction available, most of the time. And there's plenty of ways to do this without getting your hands dirty with manual semaphores - of course, at some point, it's probably still used, but if you can get by withouth doing that manually, you probably should. I've had code where semaphores were indeed the best choice, but I try to avoid those if there's a better way. In fact, you rarely want to use manual threads either - using e.g. `Parallel.ForEach` or `Task`s should be a better choice for most multi-threading / asynchronous code needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your start method as follows:

```
 public void start()
 {
    List<Thread> myThreads = new List<Thread>();
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
       Thread t = new Thread(Step1);
       myThreads.Add(t);
       t.Start(x);                              
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for threads to complete");
    foreach (Thread t in myThreads)
       t.Join();
    Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");            
 }
```

If you wanted to wait on the Step2's completing as well, you could do something like this:

```
    static SemaphoreSlim _sem = new SemaphoreSlim(5);
    static List<Thread> step2Threads = new List<Thread>();

    public void start()
    {
        List<Thread> step1Threads = new List<Thread>();
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(Step1);
            step1Threads.Add(t);
            step2Threads.Add(new Thread(Step2));
            t.Start(x);                              
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Step1 threads to complete");
        foreach (Thread t in step1Threads)
            t.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Step2 threads to complete");
        foreach (Thread t in step2Threads)
            t.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
    }

    public void Step1(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            _sem.Wait();

            int x = (int)o;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Step 1: {0}", x));
            step2Threads[x].Start(x);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        finally
        {
            _sem.Release();
        }
    }

    public void Step2(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            _sem.Wait();

            int x = (int)o;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Step 2: {0}", x));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        finally
        {
            _sem.Release();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not going to work, because `Step1` starts a new thread on its own (for some reason) - you will only wait for all the `Step1`s, not the `Step2`s.

Comment: This is true, although the question did ask about waiting on the Step1's

Comment: @Luaan I edited the answer to include an alternative for waiting on the Step2's as well